# How to unbind Sonar server from the project in VS2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, code-analysis, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

How does one disconnect/unbind/decouple the Sonar server from the project? I see no option to Disconnect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to official [wiki](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-visualstudio/wiki/Connected-Mode#removing-a-solution-from-connected-mode).

`There is not an "unbind" command to disconnect a solution from SonarQube/SonarCloud. Instead, simply delete the .sonarlint folder and its contents.`